# React JS: Having issue with CREATE_REACT_APP when using npx command in VS Code

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

Firstly, I am new to using npm AND react JS and the like so be gentle lol. I am having a great deal of trouble creating a new react application using the npm CLI in Visual Studio Code. The error log text is below in full:

---

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'create-react-app@latest',
1 verbose cli   '--global',
1 verbose cli   '--prefix',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\xxxx\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm-cache\\_npx\\7488',
1 verbose cli   '--loglevel',
1 verbose cli   'error',
1 verbose cli   '--json'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.6
3 info using node@v12.18.3
4 verbose npm-session aeaef96635f9906e
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readGlobalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 404 https://github.com/npm/npm-registry-couchapp/create-react-app 458ms
8 http fetch GET 404 https://github.com/npm/npm-registry-couchapp/create-react-app 177ms
9 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for create-react-app@latest 404 Not Found - GET https://github.com/npm/npm-registry-couchapp/create-react-app - Not Found
10 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 1ms
11 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 804ms
12 verbose stack Error: 404 Not Found - GET https://github.com/npm/npm-registry-couchapp/create-react-app - Not Found
12 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-fetch\check-response.js:114:15
12 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
13 verbose statusCode 404
14 verbose pkgid create-react-app@latest
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\Development\Courses\JavaScript\react_todo
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18363
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "create-react-app@latest" "--global" "--prefix" "C:\\Users\\xxxx\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm-cache\\_npx\\7488" "--loglevel" "error" "--json"
18 verbose node v12.18.3
19 verbose npm  v6.14.6
20 error code E404
21 error 404 Not Found - GET https://github.com/npm/npm-registry-couchapp/create-react-app - Not Found
22 error 404
23 error 404 'create-react-app@latest' is not in the npm registry.
24 error 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
25 error 404 Note that you can also install from a
26 error 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
27 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

---

Obviously I can see that the github path it is trying to reach with the GET request does not exist and I have looked on quite a number of sites  for this issue and everything I have tried so far has failed to fix the issue.

I have tried: **npm uninstall -g** followed by **npm install -g create-react-app**

I have tried clearing the npm cache using **npm cache clean --force**

Basically I am at loss and would truly greatly appreciate any guidance offered.

Thanks in advance!
Dan

EDIT: The below is the text i get when i run the **npx create-react-app myApp**

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://github.com/npm/npm-registry-couchapp/create-react-app - Not Found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'create-react-app@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-08-03T13_11_39_879Z-debug.log
Install for [ 'create-react-app@latest' ] failed with code 1
```

Comment: Are you using a proxy? Did you try installing the latest Node.js version?

Comment: I was using a VPN but have disconnected and tried again with no luck. I have only installed Node JS last night so on the latest version. Just in case, i repaired the install of Node JS just to be sure but that didn't resolve the issue either. Thank you Edit: I am NOT using a proxy

Comment: Try to use `npx create-react-app APP_NAME`

Comment: That IS how I was attempting to create the react application. The full command line is as follows: "npx create_react_app ." using the full stop to name project same as folder name. Thanks.

Comment: It is `create-react-app`. Use hyphens, not underscores.

Comment: Yes that was a typo in the comment from me. I have been using hyphens. I have added an edit to the question (terminal output in VS Code when i run the command)

Answer (score 1):

The issue was the wrong registrty was being pointed at. Fixed with `npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.com/` run from a prompt or terminal. Thanks for those who attempted to help.

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, if you want to create an app from `npm`, try:

```
npm init react-app my-app
```

there is also a way using `yarn`:

```
yarn create react-app my-app
```

Check [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/) for more info about create an app with create-react-app.

Comment: Thank you Giovanni, I had already tried these as well. I think it's just something to do with npm looking to the wrong git hub repository for the create-react-app. But I'm not sure where it is getting the url from. It is looking for https://github.com/npm/npm-registry-couchapp/create-react-app but from what I can see it should be pointing to https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app

Comment: I really don't know... I found [this](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8465) that is not precisely your problem (they talking about  https://registry.npmjs.org/error-ex) but it's the same registry problem. Someone solved using VPN. You could try...